# Condition for a compact set to be the support of a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* exercises and I am currently thinking about the following:

> Is there a characterization of the class of compact sets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are supports of continuous functions? Is this characterization valid in other topological spaces?

For the first question, I have come to a seemingly necessary and sufficient condition on $K$, which may be a bit too complicated : $K$ is the support of a continuous function iff for all $x\in K$, for all neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there exists a nonempty open set $U\subset K\cap V$. The fact that it is necessary is pretty obvious, and for the sufficient aspect, I have considered the connected components of such a $K$, which are segments. I call a ''trivial segment'' a segment which is a singleton. Putting aside the trivial case where $K$ is empty, there is at least one nontrivial segment among the connected components of $K$. The following two cases can arise:

- If the number of nontrivial connected components is finite, there is no trivial segment and $f$ can be defined as a triangle-shape function on all the connected components and $0$ otherwise. $f$ is continuous and has support $K$.
- If the number of nontrivial connected components is infinite, it is countable and the nontrivial components can be ordered as $\{C_n\}_{n>0}$. On each $C_n$ $f$ is defined as a triangle-shape function of height $1/n$, and $0$ outside of $\cup_{n>0}C_n$. Again, $f$ is continuous and has support $K$.

I am now considering the extension to other spaces and I can't really figure out a way to generalize the result. The necessary condition on $K$ seems to remain valid on a general topological space, but for the other part of the proof, I have used the particular nature of the connected sets of $\mathbb{R}$, which cannot be used in the general case. Is there a way to claim a more general result, maybe involving a simpler characterization?

Comment: A shorter way to state the condition is that $K$ be the closure of its interior, $K = \overline{\overset{\circ}{K}}$. That is a necessary condition in all spaces. Sufficiency is given in Hausdorff spaces, since compact Hausdorff spaces are normal ($T_4$).

Comment: @Daniel : $\:$ I think you would need "perfectly normal" ($T_6$), since another necessary condition $\hspace{.88 in}$ is that $K$'s interior is a countable union of closed sets. $\;\;\;$

Comment: Right. Forgot about that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed much simpler! If I understood correctly the Wikipedia definition of perfectly normal spaces though, the sufficient condition is actually ''artificially'' included in the definition of $T_6$.

Comment: Well, every [metrizable space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets.2C_topology_and_convergence) is $T_6$. $\:$ Also, this characterization applies to _all_ $\hspace{1.74 in}$ subsets of the domain, not just the compact subsets. $\;\;\;$

Comment: In a *metric* space, if $K$ is the closure of its interior (your condition a.k.a. *regular closed*) can't you just define $f(x)$ to be the distance from $x$ to the complement of $K$?

Answer (score 0):

I also come to this problem while studying Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. I think it can be generalized as this:
suppose X is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then its compact subset K support a continuous function if and only if K exists an open subset
Proof:
(sufficiency)
suppose K exists non-empty open subset V, then by theorem 2.7 and Urysohn's lemma, there exist such a non-zero continuous function.
(necessity)
suppose f is a non-zero continuous function support by K and K does not exist a non-empty open subset, then f(K) contains more than 1 element, from Hausdorff space we know their exist an open set W which covers only part of f(K) and f-1(W) is an open set belong to K
contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Answer isn't clear at all what it's trying to say. Maybe use proper notation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is a normal space. $K \subset X$ is support of a continuous function $f$ if and only if there exists $V \in \Gamma(X)$, such that:

1. $V = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}F_n$, where $F_n^c \in \Gamma(X)$. i.e. $V$ is an $F_\sigma$ set.
2. $K = \bar V$, i.e. $K$ is the closure of $V$.

Suppose $K$ is support of a continuous function $f$. Let $V = \{x|f(x)\not= 0\}$. $V \in \Gamma(X)$ as $f$ is continuous. We have $K = \bar V$ by definition of support. Set $F_n = \{x:|f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $F_n$ is closed and $V = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n$. Therefore $V$ is an $F_\sigma$.

Now suppose $K = \bar V$ and $V$ is an $F_\sigma$ set. Let $V = \cup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n$. By [Urysohn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma), $\exists f_n:X \rightarrow [0,2^{-n}]$ such that $f$ is continuous, $x \in F_n \implies f_n(x) = 2^{-n}$ and $x \in V^c \implies f_n(x) = 0$.

Set $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ and $g_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$. The functions $g_N$ are continuous and $f$ is the uniform limit of $g_N$ with $N \rightarrow \infty$. By [Uniform limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem), $f$ is continuous. If $x \in V$, then $x \in F_n$ for some $n$,$\implies f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2^{-n}} > 0$. For $x \in V^c, f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0$. Therefore $V = \{x|f(x)\not= 0\}$ and $K = \bar V$ is the support of $f$.